# Simple jQuery-Ajax-PHP example

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been looking at a few introductory examples of how to use ajax with jQuery but when I try those examples on my server, they don't seem to work.

Here is the code I have in the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $.get("ajax/json-statistics.php", function(data){
        alert("hello");});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code I have in the PHP file:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Both files are located in the same directory. When I go to the html page, it's just blank but I'm expecting an alert box to appear containing the text hello.

Comment: Have you put `jquery.js` there too?

Comment: When both the files are in same directory then why you have mentioned
 `$.get("ajax/json-statistics.php",...` like this?
it should be 
`$.get("json-statistics.php",...`

Comment: Ya sorry, I fixed that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You're supposed to give a comprehensive image of how exactly it does not work when you're asking for anything. Are there any error messages in Firebug? See the Network tab in Firebug and click on XHR and then tell us what the error/response is.

Comment: Hopefully your php-apache server is running :)

Comment: The issue was that I had created this file inside notepadd++ and then transferred it via ftp so there may have been some permission issues. When I created the php file directly through my server it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I found this working in my end

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("ajax/json-statistics.php", function(data){
    alert("hello");}, "json");
});
</script>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work on my end. I'm running ubuntu server btw with PHP 5.3.3 installed.

Comment: check whether the requested page path is correct. also specify the return type as "json". I dint alter your json-statistics.php code and its working fine here.

Answer (score 1):

**Check the paths** - they are **relative** and thus the files they point browser to should be in correct location (maybe they already are - we do not have enough data).

If it still does not work, there may be other issues. Eg. maybe you have the JavaScript turned off?

The best way to check whether requests have been sent and whether there were any other problems is to use some debugging tools. I suggest Chrome's **Developer Tools** of Firefox's **Firebug** - check with them, whether the requests for files and for data are sent to correct locations and check whether there are any additional JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```